# Not enough space on a shared folder...how can I increase space?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I am a teacher and I try to troubleshoot issues at a school because we don't have a network administrator or an IT person.

We store data for our office management program on a folder that is shared through our LAN on homegroup. The computer that the folder is on uses windows 7.

It seems that this folder has run out of space because it has a limited amount of hard drive space allocated to it. We are now getting an error when we try to add anything to the folder (see screenshot below)

Is there a way to increase the amount of disk space allocated to the shared folder?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your disk is full, the only way is to buy a larger one and transfer the data or make more room by erasing data already on the disk or you can compress the data.

Comment: I see, so it's the host computer's hard drive that is full. There is no limit on the folder itself?

Comment: That's probably the case. Go to the computer hosting the shared folder and right click on the drive the folder is in (most likely Local Disk C:) and select Properties. You'll see a pie chart that shows how much storage is available and how much is used. You can decide how to deal with the issue from there (clear space or get a new drive most likely)

Comment: Nate, you're spot on. I seem to have misunderstood the issue. This makes this much easier to deal with. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Folders can be as large as necessary (I believe there are actual limits, but they're huge, huge enough that you don't need to think about them). The limitation is the available storage the folder exists on. Basically, the size of the disk/drive the folder is on.